# Get current version of repository

Tags: git

I'm new to GIT, but i can't find out how to :

1. Get the version of a repository (folder offline)
2. Get the last version of a repository (online)

I can only compare the two, but it doesn't give me any information about the version. : `git status`, just tell me it's up to date.

How can i have something like this :

```
Your version : 1.9.0
Latest version : 1.10.1
```

With `conky` as example : https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky

Comment: What Sam Varshavchik said :)  Also, look here: https://githowto.com/tagging_versions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's really no clean way to do this, since "current" version of the repository means different things to different people.  It also strongly depends on whether or not tags are used.

In this scenario, if you want to rely exclusively on the tags, then you can use `git tag -l` to get a listing of all tags, with the most recent one created being the last entry.

If you want the most recently committed work, you'd have to look at the branches of your own volition and inspect when something was committed.  In this case, it's master, so all you'd need to do is perform a log on it.

```
git checkout master && git log
```

Comment: Thanks, i also like the output of the last commit : `git log -n 1`

Comment: this format ever better for my future usage : `git log --pretty="%H - %cd" -n 1`

Answer (score 4):

Git repositories don't have any kind of a monolithic "version", that they can be labeled with.

A git repository has one or more branches, with some commit at the head of each branch.

Git repositories also have a few other ancillary details, like tags.

Git is not like subversion, or CVS. There is no monolithic "version" identifier that gets incremented with every commit. Git doesn't work like that.

Comment: Also, `git branch -vv` shows you if you are ahead or behind a remote branch.

Comment: If i'm only interested in the default master branch : https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/releases on this link you can see just under the "Latest release" green button is a TAG icon with a text inside (v1.10.1 in this case) If this TAG exist, is there really no way to request that with a git command ?

Comment: @bobdylan - If you are interested only in the master branch: "git log --format=short master^..master" displays the commit at the head of the master branch. The long hexadecimal string next to "commit" specifies the head commit, which would be the concept that's closest to the "version" of the branch.

Answer (score 3):

This describes your version of master:

```
git describe --abbrev=7 --always  --long --match v* master
```

This describes the master on the remote repo:

```
git describe --abbrev=7 --always  --long --match v* origin/master
```

The version will look like this:

```
v1.11.5-25-gb2a5a47
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always execute a git fetch command (which will cover both of your questions)

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

This command will update your local repository with all the latest code from the remote repository.

Once you do it you can merge code into your branch from the local repo (offline)