# Get current project version of repository Github

Tags: github

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691373/get-current-version-of-repository) I would like to know if there's a way to check current version of a repo directly from the website (without Git command line). I need this for a web scraping bot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the latest tag of a given repo using github API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109673/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-latest-tag-of-a-given-repo-using-github-api-v3)

Answer (score 3):

By using the REST API, you can get the latest release at:

`https://api.github.com/repos/$org/$repo/releases/latest`

Comment: I didn't know about the API. Thank you @Missali.