# Installing specific package versions with pip from git private repo

Tags: python, pip

I'm deploying some custom packages with pip straight from my company's private git repo (and it's awesome). But what if I want to install a specific version of my package?

This question completements [Specify extras_require with pip install -e](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239714/6271889).

I'm trying to install it with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project==0.0.1[extra]
```

But I get a `ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'project==0.0.1[extra]'` message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git@v0.0.1#egg=project[extra]
```

Of course, assuming version `0.0.1` exists.

If your project is in a subfolder:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/user/project.git@v0.0.1#egg=project[extra]&subdirectory=my_subprojects/subproject"
```

From [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git)

Comment: Should note that "version" in this case is the git version (such as a tag) not the package version (such as one listed in a `setup.py` or config file). I was able to find my version using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416333/3761310 - Since I wasn't tagging my package repo, the version was the short hash of the most recent commit.